# Multiple source fields vs one unique source field in auto-suggest

Tags: azure, autocomplete, azure-cognitive-search, autosuggest

How will multiple sourceFields vs single sourceField for a single index of auto-suggest affect the performance of auto-suggest and auto-complete?

Comment: Can you elaborate the scenario where such performance evaluation is needed? How many fields do you plan to run Autosuggest/Autocomplete against?

Answer (score 1):

***Assumption***: Performance means latency of these operations.

**AutoSuggest** is similar to search except that it allows fast and efficient partial term queries. Specifying more fields in `searchFields` parameter *might* result in slightly higher latencies as there are more fields to match the term against. Similarly for **Autocomplete** a completed token matching the partial input token is searched in all specified fields and increasing field count might increase the execution time.

In practice there are many other factors in play like the query composition, index size and schema, service workload, caching, ranking, serialization/deserialization of request and response etc. which might mitigate or overshadow any performance degradation in the core Autosuggest/Autocomplete operation. So the net E2E performance depends on the use-case. The Azure Search team recommends doing testing with user's workload to get actual performance numbers based on the target scenario.